# How to prevent information on my ggplot2 timeline chart from being cut off

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am drawing a timeline chart with ggplot and it's plotting just fine, the problem comes in when the plot cuts off the names of the last organisations on my chart. 
I changed the names of the organisations in my reproducible example but i have tried to retain the number of characters.

I tried making it a plotly graph so i can specify the margins but the names are still cut off.
Any help is really appreciated.
An image showing the graph is attached [time line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCrCp.png)

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(plotly)

mydata<- "Jurisdiction  Organisations Years.Start Years.End
Pan-African hfgvdbxvbdxncvnbx  1998  2018
International AfrimenRis  2006  2018
International AVSG  1984  2018
Local BOSCOUGYTRtruhjhjhgpp  2007  2018
International CarhIntemmnatoponal 1998  2018
International Caropkg 1980  2018
Local ChrjslignCounselling 2002  2018
Local GWWD-GIO  2004 2018
Local Hmgngnfhfhjdhfvhg  1994  2018
International bsbbjsdvvsnvfncvsjvbsdvvnbvcndbcv  1998  2018
International gkhvhdvfjvbvccvnbdvjbv 2006 2018
Local jhfdjhfgjhseghdfhjsgdjhgfjb 1998 2018
International bjhdbfvjhbjhgdbfvjhvsd  1998 2018
International vdcxnbvndbxcvbnvnbx 2006  2018
Local ACNEVTsvdcxbnvdjxbvfn 2007  2018
International ghjbgjxbdfngvcbdjfhcgbv 1986  2016"

usedata <- read.table(text=mydata, header = TRUE)
usedata$date<-with(usedata, ymd(sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", Years.Start, 1, 1)))
usedata$date2<-with(usedata, ymd(sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", Years.End, 1, 1)))
usedata<-usedata[with(usedata, order(date)),]

jurisdiction_level<-c("International", "Local", "Pan-African")
jurisdiction_colors <- c("#0070C0", "#00B050", "#FFC000")

positions <- c(0.5, -0.5, 1.0, -1.0, 1.5, -1.5)
directions <- c(1, -1)

line_pos <- data.frame(
  "date"=unique(usedata$date),
  "position"=rep(positions, length.out=length(unique(usedata$date))),
  "direction"=rep(directions, length.out=length(unique(usedata$date)))
)

usedata<- merge(x=usedata, y=line_pos, by="date", all = TRUE)
usedata<-usedata[with(usedata, order(date,  Jurisdiction)), ]


text_offset <- 0.2

usedata$year_count <- ave(usedata$date==usedata$date, usedata$date, FUN=cumsum)
usedata$text_position <- (usedata$year_count * text_offset * usedata$direction) + usedata$position



##############displaying all years
year_date_range <- as.Date(seq(min(usedata$date) , max(usedata$date) , by='year'), origin = "1970-01-01")
year_format <- format(year_date_range, '%Y')
year_df <- data.frame(year_date_range, year_format)

#png(file="timeline.png",width=1000,height=700,res=70)
####################################PLOT#####################################
timeline_plot<-ggplot(usedata,aes(x=date,y=0, col=Jurisdiction, label=Organisations))
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+labs(col="Organisations")
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+scale_color_manual(values=jurisdiction_colors, labels=jurisdiction_level, drop = FALSE)
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+theme_classic()

########### Plot horizontal black line for timeline
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_hline(yintercept=0, 
                                        color = "black", size=0.3)
# Plot vertical segment lines for milestones
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_segment(data=usedata[usedata$year_count == 1,], aes(y=position,yend=0,xend=date), color='black', size=0.2)

# Plot scatter points at zero and date
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_point(aes(y=0), size=3)

# Don't show axes, appropriately position legend
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
                                   axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                                   axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                                   axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                                   axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
                                   axis.text.x =element_blank(),
                                   axis.ticks.x =element_blank(),
                                   axis.line.x =element_blank(),
                                   legend.position = "bottom"
)


# Show year text
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_text(data=year_df, aes(x=year_date_range,y=-0.2,label=year_format, fontface="bold"),size=2.5, color='black')
# scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", breaks=seq(as.Date("1979-12-01"),as.Date("2008-06-01") ,by= "1 year" )) 

# Show text for each milestone
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_text(aes(y=text_position,label=Organisations),size=3)
print(timeline_plot)

#####Making it a plotly graph
timeline_plot1<-ggplotly(timeline_plot) %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE,margin = list(l = 120, b =90) )
print(timeline_plot1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to change the limits:

```
timeline_plot <- timeline_plot() + 
      xlim(as.Date("1977-01-01"), as.Date("2010-01-01"))
```

Next, since the horizontal line is now too long, remove the `geom_hline` call and instead use

```
timeline_plot <- timeline_plot + 
  geom_segment(data=NULL, 
               aes(y=0, yend=0, 
               x=as.Date("1979-01-01"), xend=as.Date("2008-01-01")),
               color="black", size=.3)
```

Result:

[image]